# Creating triangle view fails when not added to x: 0 and y: 0

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

This code works when the frame's x and y are 0, but fails when using different x and y's:

```
class Triangle: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let startX = self.center.x
        let startY: CGFloat = 0
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height))
        path.close()
        UIColor.green.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func animate(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let triangleView = Triangle(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 30, height: 30))
        triangleView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.addSubview(triangleView)
    }
}
```

This works:

```
 let triangleView = Triangle(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
```

When failing it looks like this:

[image]

Well that is one ugly triangle. Why does it works with x: 0 and y:0 and fails when using different floats there? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace let startX = self.center.x with let startX = self. bounds.width / 2

Comment: Yes thanks it worked, weird it didn't do it my way... looks like the same value. 3 minutes to accept

Comment: No, they are not same values. That's why your code only worked when origin is 0,0

Comment: UIView's center is respect to its super view which means the view's origin is counted.